# Generate hollow cube matrix

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I want to generate a matrix of cubes with ***x*** volume, but I want only the cubes on the surface (Cubes I can see).
The next code does what it does, a whole matrix. How I get what I need?

```
public class World : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube;
    public int volume;

    private void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0, x = 0; x < volume; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < volume; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < volume; z++)
                {
                    i++;
                    var go = Instantiate(cube);
                    go.name = "Cube " + i;
                    go.transform.position = new Vector3
                    {
                        x = x,
                        y = y,
                        z = z
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about only using the outer limits and ignore anything between

```
// ignores the cubes that are not placed on the limits
if (x != 0 && x != volume - 1 && y != 0 && y != volume - 1 && z != 0 && z != volume - 1) continue;

i++;

var go = Instantiate(cube);
go.name = "Cube " + i;
go.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```

or if it's easier to understand

```
// only spawns cubes that are placed on the limits
if (x == 0 || x == volume - 1 || y == 0 || y == volume - 1 || z == 0 || z == volume - 1)
{
    i++;

    var go = Instantiate(cube);
    go.name = "Cube " + i;
    go.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
}
```

---

as Eliasar mentioned I also would recommend to use a better variable name than `i` e.g. as yourselve said `index`. In the end it's just a name but it's cleaner. However I would also recommend to move it outside of the `for` definition like

```
int index = 0;
for(int x = 0; ...)
```

instead of

```
for(int index = 0 , x = 0; ...)
```

which is very hard to read

Comment: Great answer! I would use a better variable name than `i` since it is not being used to iterate on. Something like `count` might be good.

Comment: @Eliasar well, is **i** of **index**

Comment: I would posit that you're iterating over x, y, and z while using i for the current count.